# Add outline links to existing PDF file using python

Tags: python, pdf, outline

Please see this snapshot first: [image: 1]

I have a pdf file in which I have to add outline links to text to navigate to their respective sections or pages. This pdf file has already added outline links but I want to add these links to text as well. Please see above shared screenshot in which I have mentioned that we have a "Product Overview" text and a number "17-5" which has link added to their respective section. So I just wants to add the same link to "Product Overview" so on.

Please advise anything

I have tried pdfkit tool and other libraries too but did not get success.

Comment: Use [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/) to extract the table of contents to a standard Python list, which you can update any way you like, using normal Python syntax: new bookmarks, changed or deleted ones, pointing to other pages and positions on the page, etc. When done, update the PDF with the result. In addition, you can add hyperlinks to any place (rectangle) on any page, to point to yet any places inside the PDF, other PDFs, internet URLs or even to invoke executables.

Comment: If your PDF has a Table of Contents in text form as shown, you can extract the link wrapping number "17-05". Then make a new rectangle wrapping the text "Product Overview" and add a link with the same target as that of "17-05". Using PyMuPDF, this shouldn't be too difficult. So I guess the message is, that once you have a hold of the target "beneath" `17-05`, the rest is a no-brainer.